# Having an Asterisk show when a user is inputting something into the menu

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello this is a basic request but i cannot find any documentation on this subject i am making a log in program and i am trying to make a secure log on however the only thing i can not make secure is when the user inputs something as it will just show all the alphanumerical digits the user enters where i want it to show '*' is there any way to do this.

My code so far (very Basic):

```
print("########## Log In ##########")
Username = input("Please Enter your Username - ")
Password = input("Please Enter your Password - ")
SQL.AccountLogIn(Username,Password,DatabaseName)
```

just for reference the statement at the bottom has no affiliation with the problem im having it is just there as part of the block of code. the Password input is the one i want to have the asterisk show up.